# Is it possible to build a real-world private ethereum blockchain without any transaction fee and what other costs should I be aware of?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, decentralized-applications

Recently I have been working on a class project. I have built a Supply chain Dapp, that was based on truffle framework and ganache as a local blockchain. I have some issues regarding the concepts of private Ethreum blockchain.

My question is, is it possible to build a real-world private Ethereum blockchain for a specific organization without any transaction fees and what other costs should I be aware of? And the second question is do I need to deploy my Dapp on Rinkeby? It's just that I read somewhere that you should deploy your dapp to testnets like Rinkeby to demonstrate that it functions well in a setting more like to the Ethereum mainnet.
Since I just used ganache for the dapp, I wanted to be certain

I found some answers online but they were not satisfactory, it would be greatly appreciated and helpful if you could provide me with some directions on the subject, as I am relatively new to this. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can. These are generally called permissioned chains. While you incur compute cost, your org or anyone given permission to use the chain doesn't pay for gas.

There is still a gas price, it is essentially useless since as the authority on the chain you can mint infinite gas. Such chains usually have PoA (proof-of-authority consensus).

You can use these clients to build such chains:

- [GoQuorum](https://github.com/ConsenSys/quorum) - geth fork which lags in upstream updates by a few months. Has lots of consensus algo options like QBFT/Raft. Additionally ships with privacy tx manager. Application level permissioning.
- [OpenEthereum](https://openethereum.github.io/Proof-of-Authority-Chains) (Deprecated) - My personal favorite. I have worked with this client extensively and wrote a public humanitarian chain spec with it (https://github.com/grassrootseconomics/kitabu-chain). Uses AuRA consensus. Well documented.
- Nethermind - Supports AuRa consensus. Haven't used it, but should have more  features than OpenEtherem.
- Geth - Supports Clique. I am not a fan of clique consensus but it can work well.

I have documented some PoA consensus comparisons [here](https://git.grassecon.net/grassrootseconomics/kitabu-chain/issues/1). You might find it useful.

Answer (score 0):

> My question is, is it possible to build a real-world private Ethereum blockchain for a specific organization without any transaction fees and what other costs should I be aware of?

No, because each transaction will consume CPU, IO and network bandwidth. These must be measured and the transaction stopped, or otherwise, one malicious transaction can halt the whole network by consuming all the resources. Thus, at least an internal unit of accounting is needed.

Comment: I apologize for my ambiguous question and appreciate the response. It's now evident that I truly meant to ask, "Do I need to pay in ethers?" when I asked about transaction fees (as I can set transaction fee to zero, which I know now).
And for the second part, I've read somewhere that you should deploy your dapp to testnets like Rinkeby to demonstrate that it functions well in a setting more like to the Ethereum mainnet.Since I just used ganache for the dapp, I wanted to be certain. Really appreciate your answer, and I appreciate the suggestion.

Comment: If you run a private Ethereum blockchain the unit of accounting is called ether by default. However, you are free to give yourself as many as private ethers as you want.

Answer (score 0):

I understand from your question that you built a Dapp and tested it using Ganache and Truffle frameworks. However, you wish to test your application on a testnet similar to rinkeby.

It appears that there are certain projects which allow you to create a mainnet fork. You just need to provide them with the infura URL of the mainnet, and they will spin up your local Ethereum mainnet fork. This enables you to test your dapp under mainnet conditions. Additionally, you may assign as many tokens as you wish to your address.
Here is a link to a repository that can perform this task.

https://github.com/yearn/yearn-mainnet-fork

To deploy your contract on the local blockchain instance, you will simply need to use the RPC URL provided by this repository.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can indeed.
Both GoQuorum and Besu allow you to create a completely gas-free network.
https://consensys.net/docs/goquorum/en/latest/concepts/free-gas-network/?h=gas